# Get name of the QImage from another function

Tags: python, pyqt5

i have a question, i'm trying to get the name of a image loaded with QImage from another function to process the image with opencv, how can i do that?

First i tried to get the name like a class variable

Here i loaded the image for set it on imagelabel

```
    def open(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
       #fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", QDir.currentPath())
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()', '',
                                              'Images (*.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp *.gif)', options=options)
        if fileName:
            image = QImage(fileName)
            if image.isNull():
                QMessageBox.information(self, "Image Viewer", "Cannot load %s." % fileName)
                return
```

then i need to get fileName to open the image but now with opencv

```
    def contraste(self):
        #Function to adjust gamma
        i, okPressed = QInputDialog.getDouble(self, "Get integer","Percentage:",  0, 0, 3.5, 1)
        if okPressed:
            print(i)

        image_name = open.fileName #this is what i tried but not working
        img = cv2.imread(image_name)
        nueva = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        nueva2 = imu.adjust_gamma(nueva,i)
        cv2.imshow("Gray", nueva)
        cv2.imshow("Gamma correction ", nueva2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you lack certain basic knowledge of python, for example in a function you can only get the object that returns the function, and in the case of a method any class attribute. But in your case "filename" is not, so the solution is that the "open" method returns the filename, also assuming that "constrict" is also another method of the same class so you must access through "self":

```
def open(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    # fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", QDir.currentPath())
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()', '',
                                          'Images (*.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp *.gif)', options=options)
    if fileName:
        image = QImage(fileName)
        if image.isNull():
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Image Viewer", "Cannot load %s." % fileName)
    return filename

def contraste(self):
    # Function to adjust gamma
    i, okPressed = QInputDialog.getDouble(self, "Get integer","Percentage:",  0, 0, 3.5, 1)
    if okPressed:
        print(i)

    image_name = self.open() #this is what i tried but not working
    if image_name:
        img = cv2.imread(image_name)
        nueva = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        nueva2 = imu.adjust_gamma(nueva,i)
        cv2.imshow("Gray", nueva)
        cv2.imshow("Gamma correction ", nueva2)
```